# Line chart zoom for multiseries d3js v5 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to achieve zooming for d3js line chart. It is working fine for single series line, but not working for multiseries. here is the svg zooming function

```
function zoom(svg) {

        var extent = [
            [margin.left, margin.top], 
            [width - margin.right, height - margin.top]
        ];

        var zooming = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 3])
            .translateExtent(extent)
            .extent(extent)
            .on("zoom", zoomed);

        svg.call(zooming);

        function zoomed() {

            x.range([margin.left, width - margin.right]
                .map(d => d3.event.transform.applyX(d)));

            // for single series
            svg.select(".path")
                .attr("d", line);

            svg.select(".x-axis")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
                    .tickSizeOuter(0));
        }
    }
```

attached working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/bmf8y5z6/1/) also, in the demo you can clearly see on mouse scroll, only one line series gets zoomed, other one fixed as it is. Don't know how to fix this. Need help from D3 ninjas.

Comment: fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/bmf8y5z6/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we would use both the datas and the line generator functions in an array: `[{line: line, data: data1}, {line: line100, data: data2}]`, bound to each SVG line with `selectAll()`.

But because the data is the same for both lines, we can take a little shortcut and use only the line generators, using the same data each time:

```
svg.selectAll(".path")
    .data([line, line100])
    .join("path")
    .attr("d", lineGenerator => lineGenerator(data));
```

This selects all existing `path` elements, bind a line generator to each of them, and then use the line generators we bound to generate the new paths, [using the data join](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39agjn06/5/)

Comment: is it possible to move circles in the chart just like lines, when zooming. Demo https://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/0k3oLwe7/12/